# Duplicate type in two different versions of the same GAC assembly, System.Web.Mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

[image]

This is the error I get when I try to run my MVC 4 application on IIS as a virtual directory of the default website. If I use IIS express or create a full website in IIS then it runs fine.

I've tried deleting the temporary ASP.NET files from the temporary directories but it does not solve anything. I've changed the target framework between 4 and 4.5, and it has no effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes... they're not the same version. If you look carefully, you'll see that one's version is 4.0_3 and the other 4.0_4.

I think you must [fix up your Web.config files](http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/03/using-custom-build-of-mvc-3.html).

Your `Web.config` files are referencing the old version of `System.Web.Mvc` while during runtime the system tries to use the more recent version.